# About the method of resize raster resolution

Tags: qgis, raster

I opened a raster file as a layer, and click the right mouse button and select "Save as..." to change the resolution. I got the new raster, but I want to know what is the method (average, aggregation...) of this mode?

Answer (score 2):

Save as... is based on gdal_translate https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html and gdaladdo https://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html for the image pyramids. By the documentation of gdal_translate the default method is nearest.

> -r {nearest (default),bilinear,cubic,cubicspline,lanczos,average,mode}:
>       (GDAL >= 2.0) Select a resampling algorithm.

I do not see a sign about using some other resampling method than the default in QGIS [source code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/9faab8162a3695c81b3eb05088c8093d1ef051c2/src/gui/qgsrasterlayersaveasdialog.cpp)

It might be worth making a feature request about about adding a control that allows user to select the resampling method.